# Cannot start docker nginx

Tags: bash, docker, nginx, docker-compose

My operating system is windows 10 with latest Docker Desktop and the app is running on node 16(docker nodejs)

Here is my nginx conf file at: ./nginx/default.conf(windows 10 machine)

```
server {
listen 80;

location /users {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass http://pwm-node:3000
    proxy_redirect off;
}
```

}

here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    ports:
      - "3000:80" # nginx listen on 80
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro

  pwm-node:
    build: .
    environment:
      - PORT=3000
    depends_on:
      - mongo

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=superuser
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=superuser
    volumes:
      - mongo-db:/data/db

  redis:
    image: redis
volumes:
  mongo-db:
```

Here is the logs of nginx container fail to start:

```
2021-12-20T11:50:31.262794400Z  /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
2021-12-20T11:50:31.262861000Z  /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
2021-12-20T11:50:31.263500100Z  /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
2021-12-20T11:50:31.264787300Z  10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: can not modify /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf (read-only file system?)
2021-12-20T11:50:31.264896600Z  /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
2021-12-20T11:50:31.266405000Z  /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
2021-12-20T11:50:31.267157100Z  /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
2021-12-20T11:50:31.269871700Z  2021/12/20 11:50:31 [emerg] 1#1: invalid number of arguments in "proxy_pass" directive in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:11
2021-12-20T11:50:31.269880300Z  nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "proxy_pass" directive in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:11
```

Comment: Missing `;` after `proxy_pass http://pwm-node:3000`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's easy: You are missing a semicolon within nginx/default.conf, you have to write:

```
proxy_pass http://pwm-node:3000;
```